# Why does this div that I toggle with slideToggle("slow") start out open?

Tags: jquery

I found this sliding panel script I like at http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/, (#1 Sample Slide Panel) and played with it in my sandbox.  The page loads both in the example, and my sandbox, closed.

So, I change it a bit to fit my needs, and got it working just the way I wanted, and was feeling pretty proud of myself, and then it hit me - In my implementation, the page loads with it open.  I need it to be closed.

This is driving me mad, especially because they haven't decided if it's cool for us to start using JQuery in our main project, and I'm using it here, because it's for a one off, standalone tool.  I know it'll look really cool to management, and am hoping they'll say, 'Well, that's nifty.  You all should use that JQuery thing in the main project.'

Here's the page itself:

```
    <p class="slide" style="float: left; width: 10px;">
        <a href="#" id="slider_1" class="btn-slide"></a>
    </p>
    <span style="padding-left: .1em;">Filter</span>
    <br />
    <div class="slidepanel" id="panel1" >

    A TABLE
    </div>
```

And then the JQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
        var number = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
        $("#panel"+number).slideToggle("slow");
        $(".slide").toggleClass("active"); return false;
    });

});
```

And finally the css portion:

```
.slidePanel {
    background: #754c24;
    height: 400px;
    display: none;
}


.slide {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(../images/menu_closed.gif) no-repeat center top;
}


.btn-slide {
    background: url(../images/menu_closed.gif) no-repeat right -50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 144px;
    height: 31px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    font: bold 120%/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.active {
    background: url(../images/menu_open.gif) no-repeat center top;
}
```

Comment: Depending on your doctype, css class names are case sensitive. Try changing your class to .slidepanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reference a CSS class of slidePanel but in the CSS portion it is defined as slidepanel. CSS is case sensitive in more common doctypes, but regardless of doctype it is general best practice to honour case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

just put `style="display:none"` on the panel's markup, that way it will start out as being hidden.

Comment: This is more a hack, as the CSS casing issue is the actual cause for the panel not being hidden. The sidePanel css defines that the element should be hidden, so once the CSS casing issue is resolved, it will work as expected.